# How to remove a list item from a lambda expression in c#?

Tags: c#

If I have this

```
private static List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();

private static void Main()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1)
    {
        Action action = async () => {
            // want to remove this specific lambda item from the "actions" variable. 
            // is there something like this:
            /*
                Action this_action = this;
                actions.Remove(this_action);
            */
        };

        actions.Add(action);
    }

    Parallel.Invoke(actions.ToArray());

    Console.Write("\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

How can I properly remove it from the list. I would need some kind of self reference?

**Note:**
It's the action that was just run should be the one to be removed. The actions may not finish in the same order as how they are added to the list, but the one that ran should be the one removed. And I don't want to remove them all at the same time, only as they finish.

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't have an `async void` method.  If those methods are asynchronous then they should be returning a `Task`, and you should be checking the results of that task.

Comment: You want `action` to remove itself from the list?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do `current_list.Remove(action);`?

Comment: @BlakeThingstad because this code snippet is wrapped by a while loop. And so at the end of the loop, isn't it the case that the "action" variable will point to the last one created.

Comment: I edited the code above. Will current_list.Remove(action) still work?

Comment: @Servy I use async, because there will be an async function run within the lamda.

Comment: Its the action that was just run should be the one to be removed. The actions may not finish in the same order as how they are added to the list, but the one that ran should be the one removed.

Comment: And I don't want to remove them all at the same time, only as they finish.

Comment: @omega Those comments are worth adding to the question.

Comment: Details added to question above.

Comment: Added pseudocode to code example to show what I am trying to get.

Comment: Made slight changes to code to make it compilable. Please revert them if they changed your intent.

Comment: Move `action` variable declaration before body assignment and initialize it with `null` to avoid compiler error. Then you can use it inside the body. e.g. `Action action = null; action = async () => { …. current_list.Remove(action); };` This technique is commonly used for creating recursive lambdas.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with this even after reading the comments.  Is this just for fun so that you can make something happen a certain way? If not then I don't feel like you're logic is correct from top to bottom; just from a development perspective this looks terrible lol.

Comment: @IvanStoev Won't that result in the action variable pointing to the last one created?

Comment: @omega No it won't, it is removing that specific instance of Action.

Comment: @omega Yes, and like I said, *you should not be writing an asynchronous function that's not returning a `Task`*, and that isn't looking at the result of that task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the reference to `action` to remove the action's instance. Closure will make sure that the reference is pointing to the correct object.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1)
{
    Action action = null;
    action = () => {
        actions.Remove(action);
    };

    actions.Add(action);
}

Parallel.Invoke(actions.ToArray());
```

See [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SZCr9j) for a working example.